# How do I get the SAVON (ROR) SOAP Header to match my C# service requirements?

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, soap, savon

I have some code on my C# webservice, that checks the header string contains a valid user.

The code is:

```
MessageHeaders headers = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders;
String soapHeader = headers.GetHeader<String>("VerifyUser", "http://companyname.co.uk");
```

Where `soapHeader` is the string I check. (currently contains username and password(MD5))

How would I send a string from SAVON Rails in the header, so that it can be pulled back off on the webservice.

Preferably without changing the current C# code, unless you can specify a way of sending from a C# client as well.

Ive tried

```
response = client.request :wsdl, :get_customer_centre_details do
  soap.header = { "VerifyUser" => "1:5F4DCC3B5AA765D61D8327DEB882CF99" }
end
```

Cheers!

EDIT: This is how I currently add the header in C#

```
OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(ConChannel);
MessageHeader<String> header = new MessageHeader<String>(UserID + ":" + md5HashString);
var untyped = header.GetUntypedHeader("VerifyUser", "http://www.companyname.co.uk");
OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(untyped);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I was missing was the attributes option, to add on the XML namespace, hence it was not being identified as the same header.

```
    response = client.request :wsdl, :get_services do
      soap.header = { "VerifyUser"  => "1:5F4DCC3B5AA765D61D8327DEB882CF99", :attributes! => { "VerifyUser" => { "xmlns" => "http://www.companyname.co.uk"} } }
    end
```